# How to stabilise the wifi connection between jetson nano and my laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi-configuration

My laptop: Asus F556UA AS54

Single board computer: Nvidia Jetson Nano (with edimax ew7811-un wifi dongle).

The WiFi connectivity is very unreliable. pinging both the systems from each other shows that they readily lose connection after every 50-70 packets. packet loss is around 50-60%.

What I've tried:

1. Using mosh. (improved the ssh experience, not the connectivity)
2. Powered the Jetson Nano with barrel jack supply. (lower voltage stabilized the connection and dropped the packet loss rate to less than 30%)
3. Disabled `usbcore autosuspend` by manually changing the value to `-1`
4. Higher voltage also seems to stabilize (I'll be connecting two logitech cameras for stereo vision so I think higher voltage is required)

What else can I do? I right now cannot buy Intel's 8265 dual band WiFi card (Is is better though?)

Comment: You should post the actual Wi-Fi chipset. Try `lsusb` to find out.